# Read temperature not updating in table pySimplegui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

My goal here is to update my table with the updated temperature.
My modbuss works, I can get the temperature and print on the screen in pysimplegui alone.
But when I added my table, it won't update or show.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time
import serial

currentTemp = (-99)  

while True:
    data_array_array = [[(currentTemp), 'empty', ],]
    headings = ['Temperature', 'Humidity']

    layout = [
            [sg.Table(values=data_array_array, 
            headings=headings, 
                        max_col_width=35,
                        auto_size_columns=True,
                        display_row_numbers=True,
                        justification='right',
                        num_rows=10,
                        key='-TABLE-',
                        row_height=35)]
        ]

    window = sg.Window("Temp_Humidity", layout)

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
    if event in (None, sg.WIN_CLOSED):
        break

    if event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT:
                
        time.sleep(1)
        ComPort = serial.Serial("COM3", baudrate=9600,bytesize=8,parity='N',stopbits=1, timeout=1,)
         
        Temphex = b'\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02\xC4\x0B'

        ComPort.write(Temphex)
        temp = ComPort.read(7)
        t=" ".join(["{:02x}".format(x) for x in temp])
        t1=(( int( (t[9:11]+t[12:15]),16))/100)
        tf = round((t1*(9/5))+32,2)
        print (tf)
        ComPort.close()
        currentTemp = (tf)
           
        window['CLK'].update(currentTemp)
       
window.close()
```

Comment: Your inner `while` loop will not exit until `event` is either "Exit" or sg.WIN_CLOSED.  Thus, you will never see `event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT` be true.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to make sure is that you only need to do something once, then put them out of your `while` loop.

- Initial condition.
- Create and close the GUI window.
- Open and close the COM port.

Prefer to use multithread to capture you data, then update the GUI.

Demo code - For testing, flag `test = True` added.

```py
import time
import serial
import random
import datetime
import threading
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def get_data(window):
    while running:
        if not test:
            com_port.write(Temphex)
            temp = com_port.read(7)
            t  = " ".join(["{:02x}".format(x) for x in temp])
            t1 = int(t[9:11]+t[12:15], 16)/100
            tf = round(t1 * 9/5 + 32, 2)
            current_temp = tf
        else:
            current_temp = random.randint(30, 85)
        current_humity = random.randint(30, 85)
        current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        window.write_event_value("NEW DATA", (current_time, current_temp, current_humity))
        time.sleep(1)
    window.write_event_value("CLOSE", None)

test = True

temp_hex = b'\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02\xC4\x0B'
if not test:
    com_port = serial.Serial("COM3", baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=1)
data, new_record = [], ('empty', 'empty', 'empty')
headings = ['Time', 'Temperature', 'Humidity']
num_rows=10

font = ("Courier New", 12)
sg.set_options(font=font)
layout = [[sg.Table(values=[new_record], headings=headings, max_col_width=35, auto_size_columns=False, col_widths=[20, 12, 10], justification="center", pad=(0, 0), hide_vertical_scroll=True, key='-TABLE-')]]
window = sg.Window("Temp_Humidity", layout, enable_close_attempted_event=True, margins=(0, 0), finalize=True)

running = True
threading.Thread(target=get_data, args=(window, ), daemon=True).start()
count = 0

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT:
        # Set flag to stop threading
        running = False

    elif event == "NEW DATA":
        count += 1
        new_record = values[event]
        data.append(new_record)
        # View only num_rows records
        index = 0 if count <= num_rows else count-num_rows
        window['-TABLE-'].update(values=data[index:index+num_rows])

    elif event == "CLOSE":
        break

if not test:
    com_port.close()
window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will try this tonight when I get home, I did intend on using table and time stamp. it was simpler for me to do little pieces at a time and build my way up. It’s pretty much exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you.